# Customer churn labeling in R

Tags: r

I have transaction data in the format below.

```
transaction <- data.frame(account_id=c('ID001','ID001','ID002','ID002','ID001','ID002'), transaction_date=c('2017-01-02','2017-01-03','2017-01-03','2017-01-05','2017-01-06','2017-01-08'))
```

[image]

I want to label which account is inactive for three consecutive months during 1 Jan 2017 and 31 Dec 2017. This is my R code.

```
library(dplyr)

list_account_id <- transaction %>% distinct(account_id)
list_account_id <- list_account_id$account_id

churn_label <- data.frame("account_id" = c('ID000'), "churn_date" = c(as.Date('9999/99/99')), "label"=c(0))

for (int_account_id in list_account_id){
    start_date <- as.Date('2017-01-01')
    break_while <- FALSE
    while(!break_while){
        end_date <- start_date+90
        int_transaction <- transaction %>% filter(account_id == int_account_id)
        int_transaction %>% filter(as.Date(transaction_date) <= end_date, as.Date(transaction_date) >= start_date) %>% summarise(n=n())

        sum_ntransaction <- int_transaction %>% filter(as.Date(transaction_date) <= end_date, as.Date(transaction_date) >= start_date) %>% summarise(n=n())
        if(sum_ntransaction$n == 0){
            churn_label_temp <- data.frame("account_id" = c(int_account_id), "churn_date" = c(start_date), "label"=c(1))
            churn_label <- rbind(churn_label, churn_label_temp)
            break_while <- TRUE
        }
        if(end_date == as.Date('2017-12-31')){
            churn_label_temp <- data.frame("account_id" = c(int_account_id), "churn_date" = c('9999/99/99'), "label"=c(0))
            churn_label <- rbind(churn_label, churn_label_temp)
            break_while <- TRUE
        }
    start_date <- start_date+1
    }
}
```

The output of my code is

[image]

However, my code is so slow. Is there another way to done this?

Comment: Your expected output doesn't seem to match your sample data. Where does the entry `account_id = "ID000"` come from?

Comment: @MauritsEvers That is a initial row for churn_label dataframe and the example of non-churn customer. I assigned it manually. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: How many distinct accounts will there be in your real world application?

Comment: @MartinSeehafer About 100,000 accounts

Comment: What do you do if a customer has transaction on 2017-01-03 and 2017-15-06? This is more than 3months so you would consider the customer as a churner with churn data 2017-01-03?

Comment: @Arno I will identify them as 'churn' (label = 1). I want to identify customers who are inactive for three consecutive months during given period. Using 'churn' word may make you confused. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### tidyverse solution

also taking into account that 90 days != 3 months !!  For calculation with months, I prefer the [%m+%](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lubridate/versions/1.7.4/topics/%25m%2B%25) operator from the `lubridate`-package.

```
transaction <- data.frame(account_id=c('ID001','ID001','ID002','ID002','ID001','ID002'), transaction_date=c('2017-01-02','2017-01-03','2017-01-03','2017-01-05','2017-01-06','2017-01-08'))

library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

transaction %>%
  #set transaction date as dates
  mutate( transaction_date = as.Date( transaction_date ) ) %>%
  #group by account id
  group_by( account_id ) %>%
  #arrange on date 
  arrange( transaction_date ) %>%
  #inactive more than 3 months? Check if the next transaction date is larger than the currect transaction date + 3 months
  mutate( inactive_label = ifelse( transaction_date %m+% months(3) > lead( transaction_date ), 0, 1 ) ) %>%
  #also check the first and last row of each group (first not after 2017-01-01 + 3 months, last not before 31-12-2017 - 3 months)
  mutate( inactive_label = ifelse( row_number() == 1 & transaction_date > as.Date("2017-01-01") %m+% months(3), 1, inactive_label ) ) %>%
  mutate( inactive_label = ifelse( row_number() == n() & transaction_date %m+% months(3) < as.Date("2017-12-31") , 1, inactive_label ) )

# # A tibble: 6 x 3
# # Groups:   account_id [2]
# account_id transaction_date inactive_label
#   <fct>      <date>                    <dbl>
# 1 ID001      2017-01-02                    0
# 2 ID001      2017-01-03                    0
# 3 ID002      2017-01-03                    0
# 4 ID002      2017-01-05                    0
# 5 ID001      2017-01-06                    1
# 6 ID002      2017-01-08                    1
```

Comment: It's much faster than my code. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Based on what is exactly your churn definition, you might be only interested in the maximum transaction date and check whether this transaction is more than 3months from the end of your dependent period. As an example you can use the following:

```
#Set up you timeline
end_dependent <- as.Date("2017-31-12", format= "%Y-%d-%m")
library(lubridate)
churndate <- end_dependent %m-% months(3)

# transaction date in date format
transaction$transaction_date <- as.Date(transaction$transaction_date,format= "%Y-%d-%m")

# Aggregate per account taking the maximum transaction date
transaction_per_account <- aggregate(list(max_transaction_date = transaction$transaction_date), by=list(account_id =transaction$account_id), max)
# Calculate a binary dependent variable for churn and churn date
transaction_per_account$churn <- ifelse(transaction_per_account$max_transaction_date <= churndate, 1, 0 )
ifelse(transaction_per_account$churn == 1, transaction_per_account$churn_date <- transaction_per_account$max_transaction_date, transaction_per_account$churn_date <- as.Date("9999-01-01", format= "%Y-%d-%m") )
```

This gives as output:

```
> transaction_per_account
account_id max_transaction_date churn churn_date
1      ID001           2017-06-01     1 2017-06-01
2      ID002           2017-08-01     1 2017-08-01
```